# How can i transfer a file from my cordova / phonegap android app to PC through USB cable?

Tags: android, cordova, usb, file-transfer, phonegap

I have an android application which is using cordova 7.0.1. In which i can transfer files with file transfer plugin. Now i need an additional feature that the files need to be transfered through USB cable. The file can be image and json / txt files.

Comment: you will never be able to initiate transfer from the phone, as it is a slave device when connected to the PC, not a master device. Only master device can do such things. If you still want to do that, you probably want to develop the PC application, which will initiate this transfer.

Comment: Thank you @VladyslavMatviienko , Any chance for transferring files into the PC which is connected in the same wifi without internet using IPV4 address?

Comment: situation is almost the same. You need an application to receive the files on your PC. YOu also can investigate  something like shared directories